# Killing foreground browser programmatically

Tags: java, android

I am developing an android app which launch my server address in chrome/firefox. I'm successful in that. Later in the development, I'm required to listen to the server which will notify me whether has my browser crash or hang. When this happen, I will need to *restart* the browser.

This is what I did, when user press the button:

```
    Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
    i.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString("com.android.chrome/com.android.chrome.Main"));
    i.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
    i.setData(Uri.parse("http://stackoverflow.com/"));
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(i);
```

** This will bring the browser to the foreground, I want this to be restarted when it hang.

How do I restart (close and start again) this foreground browser that was launch by my app programmatically?

Comment: We're glad you have a question! Since you are asking one (by clicking the "Ask Question" button, you don't really need to say it again :). Any code that you have (perhaps the code that starts the browser) will be very helpful to those trying to answer. Otherwise this is a pretty good question! Also, please do not put tags in your title, thats what they are there for!

Answer (score 0):

if your are running on activity you can just call recreate(); to recreate the whole activity that will also restart the server call. If you are running it on a service, then you can use stopSelf(); but then you'll have to notify the activity to recreate it